# jQuery Infite Scrolling without PHP possible?

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm been spending so much time to look around about a plugin on jQuery that has a inifite scrolling feature. Mostly it's always PHP,MySQL together. Do you have any suggestion for a front-end  Infinite scrolling? I am building a gallery of picture that loads almost 500 images.

```
        <section class="work">

            <figure class="new_release">
                <a rel="new_release" class="fancybox" href="images/big/1.png" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean eleifend mauris tincidunt dui mattis lacinia vel nec orci. Aliquam eget.">
                    <img src="images/1.png" alt="afadsf" />
                    <dl>
                        <dt>Client</dt>
                            <dd>Envato</dd>
                        <dt>Role</dt>
                            <dd>Popularity</dd> 
                    </dl>
                </a>    
            </figure>   

            <figure class="Popularity">
                <a rel="Popularity" class="fancybox" href="images/big/2.png" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean eleifend mauris tincidunt dui mattis lacinia vel nec orci. Aliquam eget.">
                    <img src="images/2.png" alt="" />
                    <dl>
                        <dt>Client</dt>
                            <dd>Envato</dd>
                        <dt>Role</dt>
                            <dd>Popularity</dd> 
                    </dl>
                </a>    
            </figure>   
                            .....
                            .....
                            .....
        </section>
```

The Figure container will be the repetitive code to display the other images..

Comment: Well, you would need to send those 500 images (URLs, at least) in advance. Then there is not really a reason for any javascriptery, except to direct the order of image preloading (which the browser isn't too bad at either).

Comment: The whole point of infinite scrolling is to load in only some data at a time when requested.  Otherwise you can make a static page that loads all the images in and just use a scrolling div..

Answer (score 0):

I came across this, it looks like its a wordpress plugin and jquery plugin.

http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

I would assume once you have a list of images you can easily manage that without the use of PHP and mySQL.  Folks are probably using PHP and mySQL for data pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite Scroll allows you to keep a page contents small at first, but then expand than via Ajax upon request.  When you scroll toward an edge (typically the bottom of the page) some sort of loading spinner is displayed.

Typically jQuery is employed for this since cross-browser scroll detection can be somewhat laborious.  So some snippet like this is common for this type of detection:

```
//Bind Scroll Event Listener
    $(window).scroll(function () {
       if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())
          // End of page reached...
          // Show loading spinner
          // Make Ajax Call
          // When Ajax Call finishes, hide spinner, append retrieved data
          // Update some counter
          // Page height is now expanded, and process can repeat
    }
```

Typically some sort of counter is kept to determine how many "pages" have been loaded so far.  This is passed to a server-side script to limit the result set to a specific page.

Optionally, with some JavaScript/jQuery you can remove the previous content, only to restore it if you scroll back to the top.

In your case, you'd probably end up maintaining some hard-coded JavaScript object that contains an array of images as your pagination process, and pre-loading them while you show the spinner, appending after all pre-loads have completed.

Comment: are you refrering to http://www.infinite-scroll.com/ plugin too?.. I have checked that but I can't comprehend how to apply it on my gallery.